# Diferença entre [ID="MAIN"] E #MAIN

Tags: css

Pessoal alguém sabe me dizer qual é a diferença entre:

- `[ID=""]` e `#`
- `[CLASS=""]` e `.`

Qual diferença em que eles fazem, código ficar maior? Mais feio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eles são parecidos. O `[]` é o [seletor de atributos](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors), e o CSS seleciona elementos que têm exatamente esse atributo.

Repara que quando usas o método `[class="foo bar"]` ele só vai funcionar em elementos que têm **ambas** as classes. Enquanto que `div.foo` atua em todas as divs que têm essa classe.

A técnica `[]` é  util para outros atributos que não `id` ou `class`, pois esses têm seletores próprios e mais simples de usar ou combinar.

#### Exemplo:

```css
div[class="um"] {
    background-color: #ccf;
}
div.um{
    border:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="um">1</div>
<div class="dois">2</div>
<div class="um dois">1 2</div>
```

(jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1rcxfrxz/)

Quando usas `div.um` ele atua em dois elementos, quando usas  `div[class="um"]` ele só atua em um elemento.

Comment: Nesse caso, ele pode usar o selector `.foo.bar`, que gera o mesmo efeito de [class="foo bar"].

Comment: @WallaceMaxters só uma nota `.foo.bar` não é a mesma coisa que `[class="foo bar"]`, com `=` o valor que que ser exato da maneira que foi escrita, já com `.`, podem haver inúmeros espaços e variações de posição que ainda sim os elementos são encontrados.

Answer (score 2):

## # (Sustenido)

Já é um caractere para representação do ID do elemento por padrão no css.

## [ID="MAIN"] (Seletor por Atributo)

Significa que você está utilizando um tipo de selector do CSS3, onde você pode "pegar" um elemento pelo atributo ([Attribute Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_contain.asp)). Nesse caso, você está pegando pelo id (coisa que a sustenido `#` já faz)

A sugestão, nesse caso, é usar `#`, para manter o seu código padronizado :)

## Expressões complexas para Capturas elementos por atributos

O Seletor de atributo é mais complexo do que isso. Ele pode pegar um elemento apenas se definimos a parte do nome de um atributo.

Exemplo

```
[class=^"box-"]{
 color:#f00;
}

<div class='box-1'></div>
<div class='box-2'></div>
<div class='box-3'></div>


[class*="test"] {
    background: #ffff00;
}

<div class="first_test">The first div element.</div>
<div class="second">The second div element.</div>
<div class="test">The third div element.</div>
<p class="test">This is some text in a paragraph.</p>
```

Comment: Puts, a pergunta mudou :\